# Deleting DB rows from different tables using one delete.php file?

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-delete

I have two tables that I want to delete individual rows from - table1, table2

I POST the row's ID to delete.php, where I run the query `mysql_query("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id=$id")`

Should I use the delete.php to do the same action for table2?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks, I will be using wordpress functions anyways -`$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("DELETE..`

Answer (score 0):

You could put your table names into an array..

```
$tables = array('table1', 'table2');
```

And then...

```
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM $table WHERE id = $id");
}
```

Comment: Sorry this isn't my problem.

Comment: So what you want to, is to define which database your script should delete from, in your ajax call?
And not how "to do the same action for table2 or do I create a separate delete file for table2" as you wrote?
Please show how your ajax is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass some kind for flag from ajax call and distinguish for different table. Like flag = 1 for table1 and flag = 2 for table2 etc... based on the flag you can make different cases or call different functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just post a new variable for the table name also, in the same way you have for the row ID.